# yii make trouble with regular query

Tags: mysql, yii

I have query that use variables when I try run it on navicat it works well. but in some reason I have issues run it on Yii.

I use this code:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$sql = "
select  s.name, s.type
from    (
        select  *
        ,       (@rn := if(@cur=type, @rn+1, 1)) as rn
        ,       @cur := type
        from    games
        join    (select @cur := '') i
        order by
                type
        ) s
where   rn <= 10 ";

$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$results = $command->queryAll();
```

this query should select 10 games names from each game type. that what happens when I run it on navicat, when I try it in the site it return me only one game name for each game type.
anyone know the reason why it happens? how to fix it? maybe how run it with criteria? please help me.

btw The reason I use this query (tnx to Andomar) is because other queries take up a lot of resources.

Comment: What does a var_dump of $results show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a `Yii` problem. Using pure `PDO`, this sql returns only one row.
Analizing the subquery results, I realized that the `@rn` variable didn't store the previous value, but `@cur` did. So, I added the `join` to initialize the `@rn` variable.

Change your `SQL` to:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$sql = "
select  s.name, s.type
from    (
        select  *
        ,       (@rn := if(@cur=type, @rn+1, 1)) as rn
        ,       @cur := type
        from    games
        join    (select @cur := '') i
        join    (select @rn := '') j
        order by
                type
        ) s
where   rn <= 10 ";

$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$results = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: tnx it's work, but I still try understand why when I run it on navicat it worked fine. you have tutorial where I can learn more about use variables tricks?

Comment: @Dennis, try the official docs: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). It says: "As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.". I'm not an expert in this kind of use of variables. In my opinion, its safer read all types first and then build your statement using `union` and `limit 10`.